upgrading alembic head from within FastAPI failing with 'no attribute get_main_option'
I'm trying to do an "alembic upgrade head" from within FastAPI.  I can run that on the command line and it works great.  But I'm trying to do something similar with the alembic commands and it's not working for me. Here is what I have:
engine = create_async_engine(
  url=get_db_url(),
  echo=True
)

async def run_migrations():
  alembic_cfg = config.Config("alembic.ini")
  alembic_cfg.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", get_db_url())
  async with engine.begin() as alembic_conn:
    await alembic_conn.run_sync(command.upgrade, alembic_cfg, "head")

I then call that during the FastAPI lifespan startup:
await run_migrations()

It's giving me this error:
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'get_main_option'

All the values exist in the config as expected because I printed them out. If I run "alembic_cfg.get_main_option", it gives the right value. I'm not sure why the 'Connection' is running get_main_option instead of the config object.
Am I supposed to update something in alembic/env.py to do this correctly?
Thanks for any help.
Jon

SQLAlchemy 2.0.32
uvicorn 0.30.6
fastapi 0.112.1
alembic 1.13.2

